# Back button between 3 activities

Tags: android, android-navigation

I got MainActivity / ActivityA / ActivityB. So I need back button works the following way. When I click on back button in ActivityB I need to land on ActivityA. When I click on back button in ActivityA I need to land on MainActivity.

Now the issue is when I use `finish()` in ActivityB I am landing on the MainActivity. But when I use `intent(activityB,activityA)` from activityA I am landing back on activityA.

I tries these variants

```
override fun onBackPressed() {//this code in ActivityB
    startActivity(Intent(this, ActivityA::class.java))
    finishAffinity()
}
```

and this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {//this code in ActivityB
    finish()
}
```

and tried this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {//this code in ActivityB
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

The flow screen is: MainActivity (click) -land-> activityA (click) -land-> activityB

Comment: From where all you can land on each activity?

Comment: @Sagar have added info

Comment: Form a-b-c return c-b-a if you're expecting like this... Remove all the  back press methods... Backstack is there.  Learn more here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#:~:text=These%20activities%20are%20arranged%20in,added%20to%20the%20back%20stack.